# Oracle 11g fetch values using offset value

Tags: oracle11g, pagination

I am trying to fetch set of records from the database part by part.
I tried to use Limit and fetch but it seems like it does not working with oracle 11g. Is there any alternative solution to do this. I have tried many in google results but nothing is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query and do what u want.

```
  SELECT A.*
  FROM (SELECT A.*, ROWNUM ROWNUMBER
          FROM Table1 T
         WHERE ROWNUM <= TO) T
  WHERE ROWNUMBER > FROM;
```

`FROM` is from which number and `TO` is to which number

Comment: Can you explain the reason to use ROWNUM ROWNUMBER ? 
I tried with numrows> and numrows< but it is not working.
Can you help please

Comment: ROWNUM means row count of the inner query. using create ROWNUMBER u can pass the row count to the outer query. You can change the name of ROWNUMBER what ever you like.

Comment: Thank you @sandun chathuranga.

Answer (score 1):

A Sound application is based on sound design. Kindly check if you are trying to achieve a procedural requirement using an SQL. If yes, it is better to use PL/SQL instead of SQL.

1. Create a cursor using the required SQL without any limits.
2. Create a type of associative array to hold the batch records.
3. Create an associative array using the type created above
4. Open and loop the cursor.
   FETCH created_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO created_associated_array LIMIT ;

Hope this helps.